# java.io.IOException: Permission denied cannot create file in Linux

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to create a temporary file under /opt/ie/var/tmp in linux, the permission for /opt/ie/var/tmp is drwxr-xr-x. I got java.io.IOException: Permission denied cannot create file when creating, below is my code:

```
File uploadedFile = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix, new File("/opt/ie/var/tmp"));
```

Is there any way I can set sudo when creating the temp file in Java? Thanks.

Comment: How are you logged in? Are you the owner of the tmp folder 'cause that's the only user with permission to write there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a shared `tmp` directory, so I think the proper thing to do is to give it a proper permission:

```
chmod 1777 /opt/ie/var/tmp
```

P.S. I got `1777/drwxrwxrwt` using `stat /tmp` from a Linux Mint system. The `t` is `restricted deletion flag or sticky bit (t)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your java application from root user, then it should be able to create the file.

Comment: Expanding on this answer, assuming root owns the folder, then only root has permission to write a file there.